# Shutdown.exe won't run on Limited User account

Tags: limited-user-account

Win XP SP3 Stand alone PC

My Username has always been an Administrator but for security, I decided to create another Admin account and change my own account type to Limited. Now, using MY account, several problems including shutdown.exe won't work at all. I can turn off the computer using Start>Turnoff Computer>Turnoff but not using the shortcut button to shutdown.exe on my desktop.

What can I do to use shutdown.exe OR can I create a shortcut to "Turnoff"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Logon as the administator, open Start-Run and type 'gpedit.msc' go to:

Computer Configuration - Windows Settings - Security Settings - Local Policies, on the right find "Force shutdown from a remote system" and double click it. Add your limited user account.

Log back on with that limited account, shutdown.exe should work now.